# AMDEP does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL

Tags: homebrew, osx-yosemite

I've been trying to use Homebrew to install [ROBOSPECT](http://www.ifa.hawaii.edu/users/watersc1/robospect/), to help me manage the dependencies (since I'm mostly a complete newb when it comes to this stuff). The lovely people at #machomebrew got me part of the way there; [here's](https://gist.github.com/sirpercival/fca16ff271cee29fc33f) my Homebrew formula. I got this error:

```
configure.ac:11: error: required file './compile' not found
configure.ac:11:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'compile'
```

and so added the `system "automake", "--add-missing"` line to the formula; however, now I get:

```
==> automake --add-missing
/usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.15/share/automake-1.15/am/depend2.am: error: AMDEP does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
/usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.15/share/automake-1.15/am/depend2.am:   The usual way to define 'AMDEP' is to add one of the compiler tests
/usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.15/share/automake-1.15/am/depend2.am:     AC_PROG_CC, AC_PROG_CXX, AC_PROG_OBJC, AC_PROG_OBJCXX,
/usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.15/share/automake-1.15/am/depend2.am:     AM_PROG_AS, AM_PROG_GCJ, AM_PROG_UPC
/usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.15/share/automake-1.15/am/depend2.am:   to 'configure.ac' and run 'aclocal' and 'autoconf' again
```

Google sent me to [this link](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2001-10/msg00047.html), which leads me to believe that the problem is with the Makefile.in, but I'm already WAY out of my depth here. Does anyone have any suggestions? Is anyone else able to install ROBOSPECT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the suggestion is correct, but looking at the ROBOSPECT tarball, and configure.ac in it, there already is `AC_PROG_CC` directive present.

Therefore, I recommend you to try `autoreconf -if` instead of `automake --add-missing`.
That command should try to rebuild everything from scratch.

However, users (and even package maintainers) are not supposed to worry about the build system and they should just use the `configure` script. What exactly is the reason why you want to call `automake` before? It is not obvious from the link to the homebrew stuff you have posted.

Comment: I added the automake call because it said it couldn't find `./compile`, and that `automake --add-missing` could install it.  Your suggestion fixed it! (and now on to other errors...)